# What's the good http status code to return on expired password?

Tags: rest, http

When a password is expired what rest api should return? I mean: username and password are correct, but expired.

[Here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-6.2) I found that

> The mechanisms for expiring or revoking credentials can be
> specified as part of an authentication scheme definition.

Is there a specification about what's the right and/or correct http status code for expired credentials? Is http status code good to handle with credentials expiration?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An *expired* password is an *invalid* password and *must not be accepted* by the server.

So if you are using HTTP authentication (sending credentials in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header), you can use [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) with a descriptive payload.

Here are some quotes from the [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235), the reference for authentication in HTTP/1.1:

> [**4.2.  Authorization**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)
>
> The `Authorization` header field allows a user agent to authenticate
> itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
> receiving a `401` (Unauthorized) response.  Its value consists of
> credentials containing the authentication information of the user
> agent for the realm of the resource being requested.
>
> ```
>  Authorization = credentials
> ```
>
> [...]

> [**3.1.  401 Unauthorized**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1)
>
> The `401` (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not
> been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for
> the target resource.  The server generating a 401 response MUST send
> a `WWW-Authenticate` header field containing at least one
> challenge applicable to the target resource.
>
> If the request included authentication credentials, then the `401`
> response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
> credentials. [...]

Comment: With "descriptive payload" you mean, ... headers? Content message? ... what?

Comment: @sensorario I mean sending a representation of the error (JSON, XML, text, etc) in the response body.

Comment: `WWW-Authenticate header field containing at least one challenge applicable to the target resource.` what are challenges?

Comment: @Cirelli94 Please have a look at how the [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) header is defined. The full definition of _challenge_ is available in other section of the [same document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

http://getstatuscode.com/419

> Not a part of the HTTP standard, 419 Authentication Timeout denotes
>   that previously valid authentication has expired. It is used as an
>   alternative to 401 Unauthorized in order to differentiate from
>   otherwise authenticated clients being denied access to specific server
>   resources.

Comment: As of August 2018, `419` is not [registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes). So I wouldn't recommend this status code.