# REST service: HTTP code for forcing a change of password

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

What is the correct HTTP status code that should be returned by a REST service when:

1. The user has attempted to login with a first-time computer-generated password;
2. The password provided by user is correct;
3. The user must change the password before he/she can continue to do anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the good http status code to return on expired password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669508/whats-the-good-http-status-code-to-return-on-expired-password)

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR;**

*There is no built-in way of doing this. You will have to rely on home-made status codes and conventions.*

---

I don't think that there is a built-in HTTP status code for a such thing.

All you can really do here is to return a `200 OK` response and add in the content of the response body a message/code telling the user that they need to change their password. If they don't, the next time they attempt to login with the single-use password they should get a `401 unauthorized` (and you can return in the body of the `401` a message telling them to change their password because they attempted to use an expired single-use password).